# Social logins profile images sizes

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, user-profile

I am trying to get the different image sizes that i can get from the social sites, like google, facebook, linkedin...

I have the data about only facebook .. 
https://graph.facebook.com//picture?type=SIZE ,

square
small
normal
large

But for google, twitter, LinkedIn how can we get the different image sizes?

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linkedin profile picture size is 80x80.
You can retrieve the original photo size with this call: `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/picture-urls::(original)` Note that this could be any size, so you'll need to do scaling on your side, but the image is the original one uploaded by the user.

Twitter profile picture sizes are:

- bigger - 73px by 73px
- normal - 48px by 48px
- mini - 24px by 24px
- original - undefined. This will be the size the image was originally
  uploaded in. The filesize of original images can be very big so use
  this parameter with caution.

(source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/profile_image/:screen_name)

With Google+ you can get the profile picture with the desired size with this call: `https://plus.google.com/s2/photos/profile/<user_id>?sz=<your_desired_size>`

Comment: update for facebook you should use like this https://graph.facebook.com/ {user_id}/picture?width=200&height=200